# MySQL deadlock error while updating within a loop

Tags: python, mysql, database-deadlocks

I have the following piece of code updating records in a loop:

```
    if connection is not None:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            for instrument in instruments:
                instrument_name = instrument[0]
                price = instrument[2]
                price = instrument_name.split('-')[2]
                type = instrument_name.split('-')[3]

                if option_type == 'P' and float(strike) > price:
                    label = 'ABC'
                elif option_type == 'P' and float(strike) < price:
                    label = 'NRU'
                elif option_type == 'C' and float(strike) > price:
                    label = 'NRU'
                elif option_type == 'C' and float(strike) < price:
                    label = 'ABC'
                print('Assigning for the Instrument = ', instrument_name)
                sql = 'UPDATE {} set price =%s, label=%s WHERE instrument_name=%s'.format(table_name)
                cursor.execute(sql, (price, label, instrument_name,))
                connection.commit()
```

Which is giving error **Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction** at the line `cursor.execute(sql, (price, label, instrument_name,))`

It does not give error when running a single instance of script, it gives error when I am running multiple instances like `python file.py 1`, `python file.py 2` etc... which I guess is locking due to once of the scripts already has a hold of the certain table.

my question is, how do I tackle this because I have to run multiple instances anyway, should I separate tables or some other hack?

Comment: Are you calling `conn.commit()` after executing the update statement?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I just updated the code. Yes  I am

Comment: I *think* one to fix it might be to have each instance handle a particular set on of instrument names, so that they aren't contending over the same rows. Someone more database-oriented might be able to comment on whether something like `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE ...` might work.